# Debug systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service

Tags: systemd

I'm having a hard time getting a [tmpfiles.d](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/en/man5/tmpfiles.d.5.html) config file to create a directory under `/run`. If I run `systemd-tmpfiles --create` the dir gets created, but it's not there after a reboot.

So to try figure out what's going on, I want to turn on debug for when the `systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service` runs. So I added a drop in file to set the `SYSTEMD_LOG_LEVEL` environment var on the service. (I see this is recommended by a [redhat document](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/4640561))

```
# /etc/systemd/system/systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service.d/override.conf
[Service]
Environment=SYSTEMD_LOG_LEVEL=debug
```

Reboot... Nothing in the logs.

If I run it manually, then I get debug output:

```
SYSTEMD_LOG_LEVEL=debug systemd-tmpfiles --create 
Looking for configuration files in (higher priority first):
    /etc/tmpfiles.d
    /run/tmpfiles.d
    /usr/local/lib/tmpfiles.d
    /usr/lib/tmpfiles.d
    /lib/tmpfiles.d
Skipping overridden file '/usr/lib/tmpfiles.d/screen-cleanup.conf'.
Reading config file "/etc/tmpfiles.d/bpm-vnc.conf"…
Reading config file "/usr/lib/tmpfiles.d/colord.conf"…
Reading config file "/usr/lib/tmpfiles.d/cryptsetup.conf"…
<snip lots of debug logs>
```

But if I run it manually, and pipe the output, I get no debug logs:

```
# SYSTEMD_LOG_LEVEL=debug systemd-tmpfiles --create 2>&1 | tee
<No output>
```

It seems that it's maybe detecting if the output is a tty, and turning off the debug logging if it's not a tty.

Any idea how to get debug logs from systemd-tmpfiles when run as a service?

....